# Transacrtion commit and rollback not working using OracleTransaction

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, commit, rollback, savechanges

I had search in the internet and not much info I can get. I try to insert data to table database oracle, but it's not working when I use `OracleConnection` and `OracleTransaction` to commit and rollback. the following code ;

```
using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
{
    string constr = "data source=10.10.10.228:1521/MPMBO;password=tax;user id=TAX";
    using (OracleConnection orcConnect = new OracleConnection(constr))
    {
        orcConnect.Open();
        OracleCommand orcCommand = orcConnect.CreateCommand();
        OracleTransaction orcTransaction;

        orcTransaction = orcConnect.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        orcCommand.Transaction = orcTransaction;

        try
        {
             MPMISTAX_HDRMASUK item = new MPMISTAX_HDRMASUK();
             //something item to include...

             dbContext.MPMISTAX_HDRMASUK.Add(item);
             dbContext.SaveChanges();

             for (int j = 0; j < Id.Length; j++)
             {
                  MPMISTAX_DTLMASUK itemA = new MPMISTAX_DTLMASUK();
                  //something code

                  dbContext.MPMISTAX_DTLMASUK.Add(itemA);
              }
              dbContext.SaveChanges();

              orcTransaction.Commit();
          }
          catch (Exception dbEx)
          {
               orcTransaction.Rollback();
               throw new Exception(dbEx.Message);                            
          }
     }}
```

I can't get error, but the table not insert in database oracle. I hope you can help my problem. Thank you

Comment: What is `Id` and what does it contain? Have you done any debugging to check it's going into the loop and calling `Add`?

Comment: loop and calling add it's no problem, but the problem is `orcTransaction.Commit` and `orcTransaction.Rollback`not work. when I not use both of that, I can save data but when I want insert other data I must click button commit and rollback in Oracle database.